# Active applications minimizing itself?

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a Mac Book Pro and I am running two external monitors, I am having issues with programs that are running minimizing themselves into my dock at the bottom of the screen.

Example: I have Safari open and running on one monitor and Outlook running on the other monitor, if I am working in Safari my Outlook will minimize itself after about 45 seconds. In order to get Outlook back up, I need to click on the icon on the dock.

This issue is not specific to just these programs, it is anytime that I have two applications open.  It also happens when I am using the laptop as a standalone.  If I open Safari first and Outlook second, my Safari will minimize after 45 seconds. What may be the source for this behaviour?

Comment: Are the windows minimized like when clicking a minimize button, or are they just hidden without an animation? Automatic termination should normally apply to only applications that have no visible windows, but have you tried disabling it by running `defaults write -g NSDisableAutomaticTermination -bool true` and logging out and back in?

Comment: When the window minimizes it is not like when clicking the yellow minimizing button. The page being does not show up down in the right hand corner of the dock.  The only way that you know that it is open is that there is a spot lit up under the icon in the dock.  As for your question " but have you tried disabling it by running defaults write -g NSDisableAutomaticTermination -bool true and logging out and back in?"  I have not tried this, How do i do this?

Comment: Just paste it to Terminal.app. If it didn't work, you can undo it with `defaults delete -g NSDisableAutomaticTermination`.

Comment: I have just tried this and it did not fix this problem.  I am still having the same issue.  Any other thoughts?